# Help generating a grammar with {a,b,c} where the number of as and bs are different or bs and cs, or both

Tags: context-free-grammar

w ∈ C*

"Generate a Grammar such that w contains strings of as followed by bs followed by cs such that there are either a different number of as and bs or a different number of bs and cs or both"

C= {a,b,c}

I am trying to do both. I'm having difficulties generating grammars, but I have understood that I should just write down some strings and from there try to generate some rules.

some of my strings are aabc, abbc, abcc, aabbbcc

I have produced the following rules:

$S\rightarrow aSbScS$

$S\rightarrow AS$

$S\rightarrow SB$

$S\rightarrow SC$

$S\rightarrow e$

$A\rightarrow a$

$B\rightarrow b$

$C\rightarrow c$

Did I do this right? And if not, what did I do wrong?

I am a language student and am trying to make my brain get used to such thinking, but I am somehow struggling with this.

Thank you.

Comment: Can any of the substrings be empty?  For instance is $b$ a legal string? Or $ac$?

Answer (score 1):

Look at it like this, at least one of the following has to be true:

1. the number of $a$'s is larger than the number of $b$'s
2. the number of $b$'s is larger than the number of $a$'s
3. the number of $b$'s is larger than the number of $c$'s
4. the number of $c$'s is larger than the number of $b$'s

So we can make a grammar for each of these, and then simply combine them.

A grammar for the first condition looks like this:

\begin{align*}
S_1&\to aXC\\
X&\to aX \mid aXb\mid\varepsilon\\
C&\to cC\mid\varepsilon
\end{align*}

The first rule means there is at least one $a$ in the string, which is necessary.
The second rule means that either we can add $a$'s to the front, or we can add both an $a$ to the front *and* a $b$ to the middle. Finally, the number of $c$'s doesn't matter.

Now we can make similar grammars with starting variables $S_2$, $S_3$ and $S_4$ for the other three conditions above, and then we can combine these with the rule
\begin{align*}
S\to S_1\mid S_2\mid S_3\mid S_4
\end{align*}

Comment: Oh I see, that's a good way.

Comment: Oh I see, that's a good way.

For now I have:

S2= aXC
X=Xb
X=aXb
X=e
C=cC
C=e

S3= AbX
X=bX
X=bXc
X=e
A=Aa
A=e

S4=AbXc
X=Xc
X=e
A=Aa
A=e

Are all four of these correct? :)

Comment: Not entirely, there's an error in your S2 rule, and an error in your S4 rule, as well as a missing X rule in the S4 case. Finally, you can't use X for each of the rules, but you need new variables since otherwise you can't combine the grammars later: they would cross-contaminate each other